# Redirect to portal home page on button click

Tags: experience-cloud, site.com, partner-portal, digital-experience, experience-builder-page

I have a button on my portal which basically runs a screen flow. I want to redirect the user to the home page after the screen flow is finished.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to accomplish this using a free package from unofficialsf.com.
You can find the package [here](https://unofficialsf.com/new-ways-to-open-web-pages-from-flow/).

Once installed, just add an action at the end of of your screen flow as below:
[image]

Within the action, just add "/" to return to main page or any other url you want to point your users to.

[image]